# PIC32 becomes unresponsive after a few hours

Tags: mplab, pic32

I have a PIC32MX340F512 board developed by another company for us, The board has a DS1338 RTCC and 24LC32A eeprom, and display unit on an I2C bus, on this bus i included a TSL2561 I2C light sensor, i wrote code in c to poll the light sensor continously , when the light sensor reaches a certain level i save the time and date and  light sensor value on SD card. This all works fine but if i leave the system without exposure to light inside tunnel where incident light on one end of the tunnel is ought to be monitored the system becomes unresponsive no matter how much amount of light you apply and then if i switch power off and back on again everything starts to work normal. i am a one man development team and have been trying to find out the problem for months, i activated the watchdog timer to prevent the system from hanging but the problem still persisted. i then decided to find out if the problem is with the sensor by including a push button to activate light measurement but still when 4-5 hours elapse the PIC cant even detect a change in the the input pin. Under the impression that a hardware reset overrides anything going on i included a reset button and it also works ok for the first few hours after that the PIC doesn't seem to be responding to anything including a reset. I was getting convinced that there is nothing wrong with the firmware but also with all this happening the display unit (pic16f1933 and lcd) on the I2C  shares power with the main unit and doesn't seem to be affected as it alternates between different messages constantly  Does anybody have an idea what could be wrong (hardware/firmware or my sensor). I am using a 24v DC power supply purchased seperately. The PIC seems to go into a deep sleep although i dd not implement any kind of SLEEP mode in my code. Nb We use the same board for many other projects and i haven't come across such a problem . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to (if you haven't already) explore the wonderful world of in-circuit-debugging (such as with the ICD3 or PICkit 2/3).  It allows you to run the processor in a special mode that lets you pause execution, see exactly which line of code is being executed, inspect variable values, and step through the code to see which parts are running and not running, or see exactly where execution takes a wrong turn.  If the problem takes hours to reproduce, that's okay.  You can just leave it overnight running in debug mode and hopefully it will be locked-up or 'sleeping' in the morning.  At this point, you will be able to pause the processor and poke around to see if you got caught in some kind of infinite loop or something.  This is often the only way to dig inside a running piece of code to see why things aren't working as you expect.  But as you say, those bugs that take hours or days to manifest are the trickiest.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can break up your design into two main parts, sd card interfacing, reading the rtc and reading the light sensor.  If it were me I would upload a version of the code that mimics reading the light sensor but only returns fake data and see if that cures the problem. Additionally do the same with the other two modules separately and see if any  of the three versions of your project not show this problem.  From there just keep narrowing it down until you find the block of code thats causing problems.

if  Two or more versions of your debug code show the same problem then my guess is it has to do with one of the communication protocols.  I had a problem with a Pic32 silicon version blocking when using the DMA in conjunction with the SPI peripherals.  So I would suggest checking the errata for your chip.

If you still cant find the problem, my only suggestion would be to check for memory leaks or arrays that are growing into reserved memory.

Hope that helps, good luck!